# Check if record exist in multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

I have here html table showing records from database. One of my column is for delete, what I need is if record is exist in both table disable the delete button. Or if record is not exist in table2 enable the delete button. Any help please?

```
$query1 = $mysqli1->query("select * from code WHERE item LIKE '%$search%' OR item_code LIKE '%$search%' OR cat_code LIKE '%$search%' order by item_code ASC");
$query2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(*) FROM app");

while($r = $query1->fetch_assoc()){
echo"<tr>
<td>".$r['item']."</td>
<td>".$r['cat_code']."</td>
<td>".$r['item_code']."</td>";
if($query1 == 0 && $query2 == 0) {
echo "<td><a href='#' id='".$r['id']."' class='del'><img src='../images/del.png' height='10px' width='10px'></a></td>";
} else {
echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)'><img src='../images/stop.png' border='0' width='10' height='10' title='Already Add in Purchase Request' style='cursor: not-allowed;'></a></td>";
                        }
echo"</tr>";
            }
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: Is this a one time check or specific to each value from the first query?

Comment: You talk about a second table yet only give the code for one...

Comment: I updated my question. How I can check record in two table? from different database

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check with `mysqli_num_rows()`. Try to check something like this

```
mysqli_num_rows($query3)
```

instead of

```
if($query3 == 0 && $query2 == 0) {
............
}
```

Also there is no `disabled` property for anchor tag. So better show the anchor tag only when your conditions satisfies. (Here, show the anchor tag only if data doesnot exists in both tables ).

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query1) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($query2) == 0) {
echo "<td><a href='#' id='".$r['id']."' class='del'><img src='../images/del.png' height='10px' width='10px'></a></td>";
}
```

Note: To "disable" a link, you can remove its `href` attribute, or add a click handler that returns false.

Comment: All of row was turn to disable

Comment: sorry I didn't get you

Comment: all of my button was turn in disable, goes all to else condition